# Using f2py for faster calculation on Python

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I'm working on a sequence alignment project with python, and python for loop is too slow.

So, I decided to use `f2py`. I don't know much about fortran, so I'm stuck to the point below.

There are two sequence named 'column', and 'row' whose type is `np.array`

For example:

```
column = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']
row = ['A', 'A', 'C', 'C']
```

I created a matrix for the `Needleman-Wunsch` algorithm, and I scored two sequences (column, row).

```
    import numpy as np
    column = np.array(list('ATGC'))
    row = np.array(list('AACC'))
    matrix = np.zeros((len(column) + 1, len(row) + 1), dtype='int')

    for i in range(1, len(column)+1):
        self.matrix[i][0] = -1 * i

    for j in range(1, len(row)+1):
        self.matrix[0][j] = -1 * j

    matchCheck = 0

    for i in range(1, len(column) + 1):
        for j in range(1, len(row) + 1):
            if column[i-1] == row[j-1]:
                matchCheck = 1 
            else:
                matchCheck = -1 
            top = matrix[i-1][j] + -1
            left = matrix[i][j-1] + -1
            top_left = matrix[i-1][j-1] + matchCheck
            matrix[i][j] = max(top, left, top_left)
```

I wanted to get some help from fortran for faster calculation, so I wrote a code with fortran.

```
subroutine needlemanWunsch(matrix, column, row, cc, rr, new_matrix)
integer, intent(in) :: cc, rr
character, intent(in) :: column(0:cc-1), row(0:rr-1)
integer, intent(in) :: matrix(0:cc, 0:rr)
integer, intent(out) :: new_matrix(0:cc, 0:rr)
integer :: matchcheck, top, left, top_left

do i = 1, cc
    new_matrix(i, 0) = -1 * i
end do

do j = 1, rr
    new_matrix(i, 0) = -1 * j
end do

do k = 1, cc
    do l = 1, rr
        if (column(i-1).EQ.row(j-1)) then
            matchcheck = 1
        else
            matchcheck = -1 
        
        top = matrix(i-1, j) + inDel
        left = matrix(i, j-1) + inDel
        top_left = matrix(i-1, j-1) + matchCheck
        new_matrix(i, j) = max(top, left, top_left)
        end if 
    end do
end do 
return
end subroutine
```

Then, I converted this fortran code with f2py, and imported it on python with this code.

```
    import numpy as np
    column = np.array(list('ATGC'))
    row = np.array(list('AACC'))
    matrix = np.zeros((len(column) + 1, len(row) + 1), dtype='int')
    
    # import my fortran code 
    matrix = algorithm.needlemanwunsch(matrix, column, row, cc, rr)
```

whenever I tried to import the fortran code
it crasheds...

Comment: how exactly do you use the fortran subroutine? please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: I did. Thank you

Comment: it is still  not self-functional: what is `self`? please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). could you not just remove the `self` part for a minimal example?

Comment: Changed it to self-functional. It's my first time on this website. 
Thank you for the advice.

Comment: In your fortran you seem to be using inDel before it has been set a value. Also are you sure your endif is in the right place in the Fortran? My knowledge of python is VERY sketchy but I would have thought it looks to me as though the two codes are different, should the end if in the fortran be just after  matchcheck = -1 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following works in my case.

File `neeldemanWunsch.f90`

```pascal
subroutine needlemanWunsch(matrix, column, row, cc, rr, new_matrix)
  integer, intent(in) :: cc, rr
  character, intent(in) :: column(0:cc-1), row(0:rr-1)
  integer, intent(in) :: matrix(0:cc, 0:rr)
  integer, intent(out) :: new_matrix(0:cc, 0:rr)
  integer :: matchcheck, top, left, top_left

  do i = 1, cc
      new_matrix(i, 0) = -1 * i
  end do

  do j = 1, rr
      new_matrix(i, 0) = -1 * j
  end do

  do k = 1, cc
      do l = 1, rr
          if (column(i-1).EQ.row(j-1)) then
              matchcheck = 1
          else
              matchcheck = -1

          top = matrix(i-1, j) + inDel
          left = matrix(i, j-1) + inDel
          top_left = matrix(i-1, j-1) + matchCheck
          new_matrix(i, j) = max(top, left, top_left)
          end if
      end do
  end do
  return
end subroutine
```

Compiling it via `f2py`

```sh
$ f2py -c needlemanWunsch.f90 -m needlemanWunsch
```

Importing into python file `needlemanWunsch.py`.
This is where your error comes from!
You need to import the compiled module see example below.

```py
import needlemanWunsch         # THIS IS MISSING IN YOUR CODE!!
import numpy as np

# create matrix
_column = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']
_row = ['A', 'A', 'C', 'C']
column = np.array(list(_column))
row = np.array(list(_row))
cc = len(column)
rr = len(column)
matrix = np.zeros((len(column) + 1, len(row) + 1), dtype='int')

# import my fortran code
matrix = needlemanWunsch.needlemanwunsch(matrix, column, row, cc, rr)

print(matrix)
```

The output is

```sh
$ python needlemanWunsch.py 
[[ 0 -4  0  0  0]
 [-1  0  0  0  0]
 [-2  0  0  0  0]
 [-3  0  0  0  0]
 [-4  0  0  0  0]]
```

Comment: It maybe compiles and runs, but does it produce sensible output? The Fortran loop indices `k` and `l` are not used (simply reusing the last values of `i` and `j`?), and `inDel` is used undefined.

Comment: the main question was how to access the fortran subroutine in python via f2py and i hope that i showed how to do that. if the fortran routine actually makes sense or not is a totally different story..

Comment: The second do-loop over `j` must be wrong.  You're initialize the same `new_matrix(i,0) ` element, which will be stepping on the wrong memory location.

Comment: @evets as I said before: the actual procedure is not of concern here as the question was rather how to call this subroutine (or any other routine for the sake of it) via f2py from python. (i just copied this example procedure 1to1 from the question...)

Comment: @jack, for the benefit of OP, I'm simply pointing out that `do j=1, rr; new_matrix(i,0) = -1*j; end do` cannot be correct.  In particular if `cc` is larger than `rr`, then `new_matrix(i,0)` is referencing an array beyond its bounds.