# Getting two values from fortran for Python?

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

Is it possible to get two values from fortran?
for example, I want to get the maximum score and this coordinate from a matrix

```
# python code 
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1, 10, 3, 4, 9],
                  [2, 1, 0, 9, 13], 
                  [3, 5, 10, 18, 3]])

max_score= 0
column_coord = 0
row_coord = 0

for i in range(len(matrix[:,0])):
    for j in range(len(matrix[0,:])):
        if matrix[i, j] >= max_score:
            # getting max_score, column, row coordinate
            max_score= matrix[i, j]
            column_coord = i
            row_coord = j
print(max_score, column_coord, row_coord)
```

This code works fine, but if the matrix gets bigger, it will take a lot of time to
find the values that I want. 
So, I decided to use the f2py for faster calculation, and this is the fortran code.
cc is column length, and rr is row length.

```
subroutine findthemax(cc, rr, matrix, max_score, col_coord, row_coord)
integer, intent(in) :: cc, rr 
integer, intent(in) :: matrix(0:cc, 0:rr)
integer, intent(out) :: max_score, col_coord, row_coord

max_score = 0
col_coord = 0
row_coord = 0

do i = 1, cc
    do j = 1, rr
        if (matrix(i, j).GE.max_score) then
            max_score = matrix(i, j)
            col_coord = i
            row_coord = j
        end if        
    end do
end do
return
end subroutine
```

I want to get the max_score, col_coord, row_coord, so I imported findthemax module 
(named findthemax.f90) that I transformed by f2py.

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1, 10, 3, 4, 9],
                  [2, 1, 0, 9, 13], 
                  [3, 5, 10, 18, 3]])

cc = len(matrix[:,0])
rr = len(matrix[0,:])

max_score, column_coord, row_coord = findthemax.findthemax(cc, rr, matrix)
```

I don't know why this doesn't work, and that's because I don't actually know 
how to return more than two values with fortran and f2py. Could someone please tell me how to 
get the multiple values from fortran?

Comment: It is easier for others to help with your specific problem if you describe/give the exact error message, instead of saying _this doesn't work_, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64909577/3967096) to your previous question indicated, you have to add `import findthemax` to import the created f2py module. After importing the f2py module, you may find it very useful to carefully look a the output of e.g.  `print(findthemax.__doc__)` and `print(findthemax.findthemax.__doc__)`, many f2py misunderstandings can be solved this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a fortran subroutine with *multiple return values* in the following way.

Fortran code `findthemax.f90`

```pascal
subroutine findthemax(matrix, max_score, row, col)
  integer, intent(in)  :: matrix(:,:)
  integer, intent(out) :: max_score, row, col

  integer :: ind(2)

  ind       = maxloc(matrix)
  row       = ind(1)
  col       = ind(2)
  max_score = matrix(row,col)
end subroutine
```

Compile it via f2py

```sh
$ f2py -c findthemax.f90 -m findthemax
```

Import it into your python code

```py
import findthemax
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1, 10,  3,  4,  9],
                   [2,  1,  0,  9, 13],
                   [3,  5, 10, 18,  3]])

(max_score, row, col) = findthemax.findthemax(matrix)

print(max_score)        # 18
print(row)              #  3
print(col)              #  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation for the maximum value and its index is *slow* because it uses *python's standard for loops*.
Numpy has tons of builtin functions that are fast/optimized and most even use fortran code underneath.

For your problem you should look into [numpy.argmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy.argmax).

Example code

```py
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1, 10, 3, 4, 9],
                  [2, 1, 0, 9, 13], 
                  [3, 5, 10, 18, 3]])

# get flat index of maximum
flat = np.argmax(matrix)

# flat index to row/col indices
(row, col) = np.unravel_index(flat, matrix.shape)

# max value
mymax = matrix[row,col]
```

Comment: While this may be correct it doesn't answer the question

Comment: I guessed that OP just didnt know about it and thus, couldnt even ask for it. @Minxo does the answer suit you?

Comment: That would speed up my calcuation, but still I heard using fortran is much faster and I really wanna use fortran for my calculation. Thanks anyway

Comment: It is worth knowing how to do it... so hopefully you can correct my stab at an answer as I do not have python set up right on my new NUC.

Comment: @Minxo I have created another answer which calls a fortran routine from python. You could try out both methods and I guess it depends on the scenario which one is faster. In most cases I would use numpy's internal routines...

Answer (score -1):

On the fortran side you have

```
subroutine findthemax(cc, rr, matrix, max_score, col_coord, row_coord)
integer, intent(in) :: cc, rr 
integer, intent(in) :: matrix(0:cc, 0:rr)
integer, intent(out) :: max_score, col_coord, row_coord

max_score = 0
col_coord = 0
row_coord = 0

do i = 1, cc    !Does this need a 0, cc ??
    do j = 1, rr   !Does this need a 0, rr ??
        if (matrix(i, j).GE.max_score) then
            max_score = matrix(i, j)
            col_coord = i
            row_coord = j
        end if        
    end do
end do
return
end subroutine
```

You probably want something like:

```
subroutine findthemax(cc, rr, matrix, max_score, col_coord, row_coord)
integer, intent(in) :: cc, rr 
integer, intent(in) :: matrix(cc+1, rr+1)  ! not zero ??
integer, intent(out) :: max_score, col_coord, row_coord

max_score = 0
col_coord = 0
row_coord = 0

Outter_Loop: do j = 1, UBOUND(MATRIX, DIM=2)
  Inner_Loop: do i = 1, UBOUND(MATRIX, DIM=1)
        if (matrix(i, j) >= max_score) then
            max_score = matrix(i, j)
            col_coord = i
            row_coord = j
        end if        
    end do Inner_Loop
end do Outter_Loop
return

end subroutine
```

A bit more elegant would be using the intrinsic functions in fortran:

```
subroutine findthemax(cc, rr, matrix, threeple)
IMPLICIT NONE
integer, intent(in)  :: cc, rr 
integer, intent(in)  :: matrix(cc+1,rr+1)  ! not 0:rr, or its it 1:rr+1 ???
integer, intent(OUT)  :: Threeple(3)
integer, DIMENSION(2) :: At_Min

! YOU MAY NEED TRANSPOSE - but just intentionally reverse rows and columns if python is row major??

Threeple(1) = MAXVAL(matrix)

At_Min = MAXLOC(Matrix)
Threeple(2) = At_Min(2) ! Or is it (1)??
Threeple(3) = At_Min(1) ! Or is it (2)??

return
end subroutine findthemax
```

Comment: So, how to get two values to Python?